# Can't retrieve ID and its column details

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm working on a movie booking/reservation system in PHP and MYSQL.Once the user has clicked on the image he/she wants to book,the next .php page should display the movie,and its details such as director,cast,genre,etc by fetching the movie's ID.
My problem is,it won't fetch the ID.

On the URL,I get a missing number of id=

> localhost/movieproject/selectedmoviedetails.php?id=

Here is my code on the php page where the user will select a movie.I'm testing one movie for test purposes.

```
                    <?php
                    $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select image,movieid,moviename,moviedescription from movie where genre='Sci-Fi' LIMIT 1");

                     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                    echo "<div id='img_div'>";
                    echo "<a href='selectedmoviedetails.php'>  <img src='upload/".$row['image']."' > </a>";
                    echo "<a href='selectedmoviedetails.php?id= '".$row['movieid'].">  <button> view </button></a>";

                     echo "</div>";
                 }
                     ?>
```

And this is my code on the php page where the user will see the details on the movie he/she chose:

```
<?php

                    if(isset($_GET['id']))    {         
                            //echo $_GET['id'];
                            $movie_id = $_GET['id'];
                            $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select schedule,image,movieid,moviename,moviedescription,director,cast1,genre from movie where movieid ='$movie_id' ") or die(mysqli_error(mysqli));
```

I'm still new to PHP.

Comment: just  check line by line code.write print_r($_GET);die(); then check what`s output

Comment: nothing is showing

Comment: post your html form code here

Comment: i have no html form since im only using echo to retrieve/fetch my data

Answer (score 1):

The error is in this line:

`echo "<a href='selectedmoviedetails.php?id= '".$row['movieid'].">  <button> view </button></a>";`

The single quote is part of the `href`, but you close it before outputting the `movie-id`. The output now is:

> < a href='selectedmoviedetails.php?id= '123>  < button>..< /button>

so the id-number is outside the `href`

On a sidenote: only use double quotes around a string when you use a variable inside that string, like: `echo "Hello $name" ;`

As you are concatinating, use single quotes: `echo 'Hello'.$name ;`

So your line should look like:

```
echo '<a href="selectedmoviedetails.php?id='.$row['movieid'].'"><button>...<button>';  
     ^        ^                            ^                 ^^
```